# Broadcast to only one client with Atmosphere

Tags: java, atmosphere

How do I broadcast messages from only one client to another with Atmosphere (Meteor)?I have currently this implementation based on meteor tutorial

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    Meteor.build(req).addListener(new AtmosphereResourceEventListenerAdapter());
}

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    String body = req.getReader().readLine().trim();
    //some DAO lookups - here I would like to say I want to broadcast only to concrete client
    BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(DefaultBroadcaster.class, "/*").broadcast(UserDAO.getInstance().getUser(name));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Atmosphere FAQ on their wiki: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Creating-private-channel-of-communication-between-Browsers

Answer (score 3):

Another solution I believe : for adressing only one client, you don't need to broadcast, you may just do this:

```
     try
     {
        r.getResponse().write(message);
     }
     catch(IllegalStateException e)
     {
        logger.error("Could not send message through atmosphere " + userId);
     }
```

where r is the resource that you can memorize in your program.

Comment: I am saving the `AtmosphereResource` s in a static Map in another class. Then iterate over them and call the `write` method you shown, but the client recieves nothing.

Comment: @kiltek it has been a while but it's likely that this solution works a bit like an http session. So you can't keep it for another time, just use it in the "session"

Answer (score 0):

```
BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(atmosphereResource.uuid()).broadcast('something');
```

Comment: This was deprecated and now thrown out totally.