# How to Broad Cast Message from JAVA server to JAVA Client in Atmosphere Framework

Tags: websocket, atmosphere

I am Using Atmosphere Framework web socket as my first preference for transmission fall back goes to long pooling ,

used runtime-native as atmosphere dependence for maven tool
Tomcat-v8 as a server

I could like to receive the broadcast message in Java Code so I refer to the following Links
http://blog.javaforge.net/post/32659151672/atmosphere-per-session-broadcaster
[Broadcast to only one client with Atmosphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156995/broadcast-to-only-one-client-with-atmosphere)
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere
https://atmosphere.java.net/atmosphere_whitepaper.pdf

From the above links and chart samples I build the project successfully but I could like to broadcast from client to server both are JAVA Language.
Also I wrote a BroadcastFactory as

Server:
BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("URL to broadcast", true).scheduleFixedBroadcast(message, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Client 
AtmosphereRequest request = atmosphereResource.getRequest();
String IncomingMessage = request.getReader().readLine();

Here while I put debug mode I got NULL as value,this made me to ask question that whether I am doing wrong or Framework doesn't support.

FYI:
I used this Link 
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Creating-private-channel-of-communication-between-Browsers

I con't get the line

```
privateChannel
   .addAtmosphereResource(atmosphereResource_browser1)
   .addAtmosphereResource(atmosphereResource_browser2);
```

atmosphereResource_browser means its define browser name?

please suggest me how to proceed more,sharing of Links or video will be helpfull.Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0):

No it's not the browser name but it is the the AtmosphereResource, who represent the browser/user to that Broadcaster. 
If you want broadcast to limited clients then you can create privateChannel and then broadcast to that channel.